# Guía de deducción para plantilla que recibe una función por parámetro

Tags: c++, template

Tengo el siguiente objeto plantilla:

```
template <typename ... params_list>
struct listener
{
    using function_t = std::function<void(params_list ...)>;

    constexpr explicit listener(function_t &&a_function) :
        m_function{a_function}
    {}

    void operator()(params_list &&...a_params)
    {
        m_function(std::forward<decltype(a_params)>(a_params)...);
    }

private:
    function_t m_function;
};
```

Si defino una instancia de la plantilla sin proveer parámetros plantilla indica que no puede deducir los parámetros de la plantilla:

```
void a() {}
void b(int) {}
void c(const std::string &) {}

int main()
{
    listener la{a};
    listener lb{b};
    listener lc{c};

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> error: class template argument deduction failed:
> error: no matching function for call to 'listener(void (&)())'
> note: candidate: 'template<class ... params_list> listener(std::function<void(params_list ...)>&&)-> listener<params_list>'
> constexpr explicit listener(function_t &&a_function) :
>                    ^~~~~~~~
> note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note: mismatched types 'std::function<void(params_list ...)>' and 'void()'
> note: candidate: 'template<class ... params_list> listener(listener<params_list>)-> listener<params_list>'
> note: template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note: mismatched types 'listener<params_list>' and 'void (*)()'
> …
> ```

Por lo que puedo ver, no sabe deducir los parámetros para `listener::function_t` en base a un puntero o referencia a función (`void(*)()` o `void(&)()`). Así que he intentado añadir una guía de deducción:

```
template <typename ... params_list>
listener(void(&)(params_list ...)) -> listener(std::function<void(params_list ...)> &&);
```

Pero he debido definir la guía de deducción mal, ya que tampoco compila:

> ```
> error: deduced class type 'listener' in function return type
> listener(void(&)(params_list ...)) -> listener(std::function<void(params_list ...)> &&);
>                                       ^~~~~~~~
> note: 'template<class ... params_list> struct listener' declared here
> struct listener
>        ^~~~~~~~
> error: trailing return type '<type error>' of deduction guide is not a specialization of 'listener<params_list>'
> listener(void(&)(params_list ...)) -> listener(std::function<void(params_list ...)> &&);
> ```

¿De qué manera debo definir la guía de deducción para que la clase `listener` compile recibiendo en su constructor funciones por parámetro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás usando mal la guía de deducción. No debes indicarle cómo llamar a la función, sino el tipo que estás deduciendo. Así:

```
template <typename ... params_list>
listener(void(&)(params_list ...)) -> listener<params_list ...>;
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##jVHBasMwDL37KwSDYFNattOgafMrQVXcYnAc4zjdRsivL7OdJunaHeaDsZ6sJ@k9snZ7IRrHF2VId5WEw7kz5FVjUBeMeVlbjT7A/stKg7WE3W4HFh3WbalV6wvWeteRhxhIIx3rGYTTtcpcYCYrPRyh9dV@PyOHa6MqfkcUiUWRs1RNjQlsn9ZBuLQitfLzO84sw3IOBexTaTz1gvbrhyGl@2HqENtDY6VD3zgufk2SZWEWLCdITGV/cPNpocZ9oKsOlSQdReJLYbE@4255ogjtrVPXoOk07t02K3POhvx/4i@qJDkz8aSogG2xaHd4yEa5kxDIRVQmvU9cGb@GxJMZk3vB62hrltIs/IMaleHiZvrcBzT2OOQP2Kk/PWHU03Dz3EnfOQOvYflx/Kazxks7bkPbI202b@8/).

---

Alternativamente, puedes crear un constructor adicional sobre el tipo primitivo:

```
using raw_function_t = void(&)(params_list ...);

constexpr explicit listener(raw_function_t raw_function) :
    m_function{raw_function}
{}
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##hVLRasMwDHz3VwgGwaG0bE@Dps2vBFVxg8FxjOO0GyG/vsx2mibtNuYHY519p5NkMmZbEY3ji9SkulLA4dxpcrLRqHLGnKiNQudh92mExlrAbrcDgxbrtlCydTlrne3IQQiEFpb1DPzqWqkrsHgtZsHCwREujSx5kvKVQlBMsxXpgdC6cr@fkUOkP3PzjEU2Ndpb@DAW/KYkycUUX2kmCd49pbCP1LDqO9ovD4Z43Q//Z3gqdR3@kWX95DFPKBMaIyy6xvLHbiWJrxmLCUon2i/qfGpcY69oy0MpSIUJ8jsxX45L/316Y@XFD3wyvKpnUc7Y4BseLSJPg@d4PnGp3RISj82a5ue/SBhsEq@Zfwc1Ss3T21@ZewgKexyyJ@zUn35g1NNwm7oVrrMaXr2tcfyis8KqHbc@7ZE2m7f3bw).